# Why can't I terminate this while loop?

Tags: windows, perl, while-loop

I made the following script:

```
print "Will accept input until EOF";  

while(defined($line = <STDIN>)){  
    print "Input was $line \n";  
    if(chomp(@line) eq "end"){  
        print "aha\n";  
        last;  
    }  
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why when I type `end` in console I can't see the `aha` and `break` from the loop (`last` is the equal of `break` right)?
2. What is the `EOF` key-combination to stop the `while` loop? I thought it was `ctrl+D` in `Windows` but it does not work.

Comment: You don't have to write it as `while(defined($line=<STDIN>)){...}`; Perl will add the [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html "perldoc -f defined") for you. ( As of 5.12 it will do this for [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html "perldoc -f readdir") as well )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script misses `use strict; use warnings;`. Otherwise, you would notice that `$line` is not `@line`.

Also, `chomp` does not return the changed string, it changes it in place and returns the number of characters removed.

In MSwin, <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> is used as EOF.

**Update**: Fixed the EOF.

Comment: If I put just `use warnings;` I get no warning for my type of `@line` instead of `$line`.If I use also `use strict` I get:`Global symbol "$line" requires explicit package name at input.pl line 6
Global symbol "$line" requires explicit package name at input.pl line 7
Global symbol "@line" requires explicit package name at input.pl line 8`

Comment: Also `ctrl+D` `enter` does not do anything.I am using `Windows 7`. I get `Input was ♦`

Comment: For windows, try entering ctrl+z

Comment: @choroba:But what about the fact that the `use warning` does not warn about my typo for `@line`?

Comment: @Cratylus: That's why you should use `strict` as well.

Comment: @choroba:But `strict` does not say anything about using `@line`. Just reports this `requires explicit package name at` which I don't understand what it means

Comment: @Cratylus: You can `use diagnostics` as well to let Perl expain the errors and warnings.

Answer (score 3):

I have modified your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Will accept input until EOF";  

while( my $line = <STDIN> ){  
   chomp $line;
   print "Input was $line\n";  
   if( $line eq 'end'){  
      print "aha\n";  
      last;  
   }  
}
```